# Selecting conditions with jooq

Tags: java, sql, jooq

In SQL, I can execute a query of type:

```
SELECT cost > 1000 AS above_k, name FROM products;
```

Giving me a list:

```
+---------+--------+
| above_k | name   |
+---------+--------+
| true    | Gold   |
| false   | Silver |
+---------+--------+
```

How can I model a similar query using `jooq`? I cannot do this (obviously):

```
ctx.select(Tables.PRODUCTS.COST.gt(1000))
```

Since, there is no method `select(Condition condition)`. Or if I just wanted to:

```
SELECT cost*0.9 AS discounted_cost FROM products;
```

Is there a way to do this using jooq?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### SQL 1:

```sql
SELECT cost > 1000 AS above_k, name 
FROM products;
```

#### jOOQ 1:

```java
ctx.select(field(PRODUCTS.COST.gt(1000)).as("above_k"), PRODUCTS.NAME)
   .from(PRODUCTS)
   .fetch();
```

See [`DSL.field(Condition)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-org.jooq.Condition-)

#### SQL 2:

```sql
SELECT cost*0.9 AS discounted_cost 
FROM products;
```

#### jOOQ 2:

```java
ctx.select(PRODUCTS.COST.mul(0.9).as("discounted_cost"))
   .from(PRODUCTS)
   .fetch();
```

See [`Field.mul(Number)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#mul-java.lang.Number-) or [`Field.multiply(Number)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#multiply-java.lang.Number-)

Comment: Even before I posted the question, I knew you'd be answering this. Thanks Lukas!

Comment: @RohanPrabhu: No worries! See you at the next question :)